# Uber style info windows google map flutter

Tags: google-maps, flutter, google-maps-api-3, dart

I am working on google map. I need to implement a custom info window...Look like this,

https://github.com/gsanthosh91/Google-Map-Floating-Info-Window-Uber/blob/master/screenshot.png

But I didn't find any tutorial designing like this custom info windows.

Comment: Which lib.  you are using for display map?

Comment: google_flutter_map

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this

```
  body: GoogleMap(
      markers: _markers,
      onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
      initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
        target: _center,
        zoom: 20.0,
      ),
    ),
```

And infoWindow in Marker class from google_maps_flutter.dart

```
Marker(
 markerId: markerId,
 position: _center,
 infoWindow: InfoWindow(
 title: 'MyLocation',
      snippet: 'Here is an Info Window Text on a Google Map',
  ),
 ),
};
```

Also try adding a custom widget.

Comment: `InfoWindow` displayed only when tap marker.. I want to show always